# 'return outside of function' error with correct indentation?

Tags: python

in python, it comes out with 'return outside of function', I check the indentation is nothing wrong. any clue on that?

```
dict={1:10,2:20,3:30}

for a,b in dict.items():
  if b==30:
    return a
```

Comment: Where is the function?

Answer (score 2):

There's no function, so you cannot use return. You may wrap the code in `def`:

```
d={1:10,2:20,3:30}

def return_30(d):
  for a,b in d.items():
    if b==30:
      return a
```

Also I renamed `dict` to `d`, because `dict` is a name of the type, and when you redefine it you lose access to original `dict`.

Answer (score 0):

The `for` loop, isn't a function.
A function in python is DEFined using the `def` keyword as in:

```
def function():
    print(1+2) # Im inside the function, return keyword here is valid

# I'm outside the function.
for x in range(10):
    print(x)
    #This is not a function, return keyword here is invalid.
```